# $R[X]$ noetherian with $R$ non noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be a ring. If $R[X]$ is noetherian, is R necessarily noetherian ?

I think that the answer is no, but could you show me the easiest example to understand ?

Comment: I think the answer is *yes*.

Comment: I found the duplicate by searching "R[x] R Noetherian"

Comment: Thank you and sorry, I've searched for a long time before posting..

Answer (score 6):

Recall that if a commutative ring $A$ is Noetherian and $I$ is an ideal in $A$, then $A/I$ is also Noetherian. In this problem, take $A=R[X]$ and $I=(X)$.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)